# Picard group of $G(k, n)$ saying about automorphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $G(k, n)$ be the Grassmannian of $k$-dimensional subspaces of $K^{n}$, $K$ a field, embedded in $\mathbb{P}^{N}$ by the Plücker embedding. In Harris' Algebraic Geometry, A First Course, Theorem 10.19 states that

$$\mathrm{Aut}(G(k, n)) = \mathrm{Aut}(G(k, n), \mathbb{P}^{N}),$$
where $\mathrm{Aut}(G(k, n), \mathbb{P}^{N}) := \{ T \in \mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{P}^{N}) \mid T(G(k, n)) = G(k, n) \}$. In his proof, Harris says that it comes down to the assertion that every codimension $1$ subvariety of $G(k, n)$ is the intersection of $G(k, n)$ with a hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^{N}$. In other words, $\mathrm{Pic}(G(k, n)) \cong \mathrm{Pic}(\mathbb{P}^{N})$, right? How such information can say about the automorphism group of these varieties?

Thank you!

Comment: This [question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/7604/indexing-the-line-bundles-over-a-grassmannian) may help you.

Comment: Thanks @YuchenLiu, but I cannot see how could it help me.